# Iteratively capture regex subgroups in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I do not know how to capture regex subgroups in Scala.

Say potions are either basic or made of other potions and they are named as `<adjective> <noun>`. There are recipe formulas as follows:

```
val recipe = "white phial potion is 3 fortify health potions, 1 vigorous stamina potion, 5 plentiful magicka potions."
```

I want to parse the formulas into the following domain:

```
case class Potion(name: String)
case class Formula(potion: Potion, ingredients: Option[List[(Potion, Int)]])
```

So far I have come up with the pattern

```
val recipePattern: Regex = """(\w+ \w+) potion is( (\d+) (\w+ \w+) (?:potion|potions)[,.])+""".r
```

but I have no idea how to proceed further and grab the iterative subgroups.

Comment: There is no way to do that like that because the value of the repeated capturing group is overwritten upon each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to capture repeated groups with regular expressions. The last match of a specific group will overwrite all the previous matches of the same group.

I recommend using a proper parsing library to parse that kind of strings. For example, using [fastparse](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/):

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

case class Potion(name: String)
object Potion {
  def apply(adjective: String, noun: String): Potion = Potion(s"$adjective $noun")
}

case class Formula(potion: Potion, ingredients: List[(Potion, Int)])
object Formula {
  import fastparse._, SingleLineWhitespace._

  object Parser {
    def number[_: P] = P(CharsWhileIn("0-9").!).map(_.toInt)
    def word[_: P] = P(CharsWhileIn("a-z").!)
    def ingredient[_: P] = P(number ~ word ~ word ~ "potion"~~"s".?).map {
      case (count, adj, noun) => (Potion(adj, noun), count)
    }
    def formula[_: P] = P(word ~ word ~ "potion" ~ "is" ~ ingredient.rep(sep = ",") ~ "." ~ End).map {
      case (adj, noun, ingredients) => Formula(Potion(adj, noun), ingredients.toList)
    }
  }

  def parse(formula: String): Try[Formula] = {
    fastparse.parse(formula, Parser.formula(_)) match {
      case Parsed.Success(result, _) => Success(result)
      case failure: Parsed.Failure => Failure(new RuntimeException(failure.trace().longMsg))
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
scala> Formula.parse("white phial potion is 3 fortify health potions, 1 vigorous stamina potion, 5 plentiful magicka potions.")
res0: scala.util.Try[core.Test.Formula] = Success(Formula(Potion(white phial),List((Potion(fortify health),3), (Potion(vigorous stamina),1), (Potion(plentiful magicka),5))))
```